# Updating the field of the nested object not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm facing a issue that react doesn't recognize the change I'.ve made on the propriety of  useState nested object and consequently not re-rendering the component.

In this case on **userPermission.data** and **permissions.data**.  It's not the first time that I facing this kind of problem what is wrong with my code ?

Here is an example:

```
const [userPermission, setUserPermission] = useState({
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    selectedRows: [],
    selectedRowKeys: {},
  });
const [permission, setPermission] = useState({
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    pagination: {
      current: 1,
      pageSize: 10,
      total: 0,
      position: ['topRight' as const],
    },
    selectedRows: [],
    selectedRowKeys: {},
  });


 async function handleAddPermission(): Promise<any> {
    if (context === 'menus') {
      // const params = {
      //   menusIds: permission.selectedRowKeys,
      //   funcsIds: [],
      // };

     // const response = await addPermission(userId, params);

      const currentUserPermissions = { ...userPermission };
      const currentPermissions = { ...permission };

      const concat = currentUserPermissions.data.concat(
        permission.selectedRows,
      );

      // data upadate
      setUserPermission({ ...userPermission, data: concat });

      permission.selectedRows.map((selected: any) => {
        const findSelectedIndex = permission.data.findIndex(
          (data: any) => data.id === selected.id,
        );
        if (findSelectedIndex !== -1) {
          currentPermissions.data.splice(findSelectedIndex, 1);
        }
      });

      // data doesn't upadate
      setPermission(currentPermissions);
    }
  }

return (
    <>
      <Collapse accordion defaultActiveKey="1">
        <Panel header={userPermissionTitle} key="1">
          <Table
            dataSource={userPermission.data}
            columns={userPermissionColumns}
            pagination={false}
            loading={userPermission.loading}
            sortDirections={['ascend', 'descend', 'ascend']}
            // rowKey={record => record.id}
          />
        </Panel>
        <Panel header={permissionTitle} key="2">
          <SelectedContainer>
            <p> {`${permission.selectedRows.length} selecionados`} </p>
            <Button onClick={() => handleAddPermission()} size="small">
              Adicionar ao usuário
            </Button>
          </SelectedContainer>
          <Table
            dataSource={permission.data}
            columns={permissionColumns}
            onChange={handlePermissionTable}
            pagination={permission.pagination}
            loading={permission.loading}
            sortDirections={['ascend', 'descend', 'ascend']}
            rowSelection={{
              ...PermissionsRowSelection,
            }}
            rowKey={(record: any) => record.id}
          />
        </Panel>
      </Collapse>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a useEffect Hook around the userPermission.data and see if you get in after your stateChange. If it does than react does recognize the state change. Instead of using useState you can use useReducer.

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 0):

You could update nested objects like this inside your input/update handler.
Spread operator only creates shallow copies. however, this creates clone of
our object preserving nested fields.

```js
// InitialValue is your current state
const initialValue = {answer: {
    highest:42,
    flag:true
}};


let newValue = JSON.stringify(initialValue);
newValue = JSON.parse(newValue)
newValue.answer.flag = false;

//You can provide this new value to your setState()
console.log(newValue)
```